# Export mongoDb data to an excel file format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoexport

We're trying to export our data in the excel sheet format. How our data looks like is as follow:

```
{
        "_id": "PR",
        "rating_group": [
            {
                "rating": "Excellent",
                "count": 3
            },
            {
                "rating": "Very Good",
                "count": 3
            },
            {
                "rating": "Good",
                "count": 1
            },
            {
                "rating": "Poor",
                "count": 1
            }
        ],
        "totalScore": 638,
        "totalCount": 8
    },{
        "_id": "RR",
        "rating_group": [
            {
                "rating": "Excellent",
                "count": 4
            },
            {
                "rating": "Very Good",
                "count": 6
            },
            {
                "rating": "Good",
                "count": 3
            },
            {
                "rating": "Poor",
                "count": 1
            }
        ],
        "totalScore": 780,
        "totalCount": 14
    }
```

We're working with mongo-xslx ([link here](https://github.com/Moblox/mongo-xlsx)) and tried some hand on around
 and we created a model in this way,

```
       var data1 = [
                      {
                          name : result[i]._id,
                          ratings : [ result[i].rating_group
                          ],
                      totalScore : result[i].totalScore,
                      totalCount : result[i].totalCount,
                      }
                   ];
```

and what we got this data in the excel file for each separate nodes (one for PR and another for RR) like below,

```
name    ratings[0][0][rating]   ratings[0][0][count]    ratings[0][1][rating]   ratings[0][1][count]    ratings[0][2][rating]   ratings[0][2][count]    ratings[0][3][rating]   ratings[0][3][count]
RR  Excellent   3   Very Good   3   Good    1   Poor    1
```

But this is not exactly what we want.

We want our data in a proper excel format like below,

```
name Excellent VeryGood Good Poor total_score  total_count
RR   3           3       1     1     638           8
```

We just stuck at this step. Looking for a solution or some hint so we can solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is format the JSON and then use mongo-xlsx plugin to convert JSON data to excel format. The following code snippet does this.

```
let mongoXlsx = require('mongo-xlsx');
let fs = require('fs');

let data =
    [
        {
            "_id": "PR",
            "rating_group": [
                {
                    "rating": "Excellent",
                    "count": 3
                },
                {
                    "rating": "Very Good",
                    "count": 3
                },
                {
                    "rating": "Good",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "rating": "Poor",
                    "count": 1
                }
            ],
            "totalScore": 638,
            "totalCount": 8
        }, {
            "_id": "RR",
            "rating_group": [
                {
                    "rating": "Excellent",
                    "count": 4
                },
                {
                    "rating": "Very Good",
                    "count": 6
                },
                {
                    "rating": "Good",
                    "count": 3
                },
                {
                    "rating": "Poor",
                    "count": 1
                }
            ],
            "totalScore": 780,
            "totalCount": 14
        }
    ];



    //place for formatting data
data.map(x => {
    for (let grp of x.rating_group) {
        x[grp['rating']] = grp['count'];
    }
    let tempScore = x.totalScore;  //temporary storage made inorder to put total score and total count at last position
    let tempCount = x.totalCount;
    delete x.rating_group;   // deleting it as it is not necessary 
    delete x.totalCount;
    delete x.totalScore;
    x.totalScore = tempScore;  //pushing totalScore to second last position
    x.totalCount = tempCount;  //pushing totalCount to last position
});

let model = mongoXlsx.buildDynamicModel(data);
mongoXlsx.mongoData2Xlsx(data, model, function (err, res) {
    console.log('res');
    console.log(res);
})
```